# Update Library Java in Google-Project-Tango

Tags: java, google-project-tango, lib

Based on project ***ParaView Tango Recorder*** following the link below, that permit to get data( device position, and 3D point cloud ), i want to develop a code to get IMU measurements and RGB-video from Project-Tango as well. 
But the problem is, the class imported in this project is too old, such as:
there's not function  onFrameAvailable() in Tango class in com.google.atap.tangoservice, which gets video data from Project Tango as the newest one. 
I think about how to update libs in this project but i don't know how to do that.
[Missing function onFrameAvailable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSqiN.png)

https://github.com/Kitware/ParaViewTangoRecorder